# How can I resolve this problem (node.js, discord.js)

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
            if (!args[1]) return message.channel.send('You need to specify a person!')
            if (!args[2]) return message.channel.send('Please specify a time for how long the ban council will last.')
            var tim = args[2]
            const sweden = message.mentions.users.first()
            message.react('').then(() => message.react(''))
            const mappo = ['', '']
            if (!args[1]) return message.channel.send('Please specify a person!')
            if(message.guild){ //this will check if the command is being called from a server
                const embad = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle('Ban Council')
                    .addField('The Convicted:', `${sweden.tag}`)
                    .addField('Rules:', 'Vote on whether the convicted is guilty or not with the prompted reactions. The ban will end automatically in 5 seconds.')
                message.channel.send(embad)
                setTimeout(function(){
                if(sweden){
                    const lyft = message.guild.member(sweden)
                    if(lyft){
                        if(message.reactions.cache.map(r => `${''} ${r.users.cache.size}`)[0] > message.reactions.cache.map(r => `${''} ${r.users.cache.size}`)[1]){
                            lyft.ban({ ression: 'Majority has exiled you from server. '}).then(() => {
                            message.reply(`The user ${december.tag} was banned as a result of a majority vote.`)
                            })
                        } else {
                            message.channel.send('The ban was cancelled.')
                        }
                    }else{
                        message.reply('The user is not in this server.')
                    }
                    }else{
                        message.reply('You need to specify a person!')
                    }
                }, tim)
                } else {
                message.channel.send('Banning does not work here!')
            }
```

*It sends the "Ban cancelled" before it actually has the chance to take input. I've tried collectors, and it doesn't work because of the max: part, how can I resolve this problem? (Also it returns no errors)*

This is in a case. (appending onto what feedback I got)

Comment: also, there is a case at the top, though it just says case 'ban':

Comment: Try using awaitReactions

Comment: @Pepe_Worm : awaitReactions works only in an async function, which I do not have.

Comment: It works in any function, it's just a promise, if you use await then it needs to be in an async function

Comment: @Karizma so do you propose i rewrite it? that works fine it just takes time

Comment: All you would need to do is wrap it in an async function which is not really re-writing it. Either way that's not the issue, the issue was that you were checking reactions on the actual message and not the embed that was sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been around 8 months since I made this post, and I found the answer, and an even more effective way to do it. I won't post the entire code, as it's pretty long and not very neat. However, this is a much more effective way of counting reactions.

My Original Code was:

```
const upvotes = message.reactions.cache.map(r => ${''} ${r.users.cache.size})[0]

const downvotes = message.reactions.cache.map(r => ${''} ${r.users.cache.size})[1]
```

It doesn't work very well either.

```
const [upvoteReaction, downvoteReaction] = message.reactions.cache.first(2);

     const upvotes = upvoteReaction.users.cache.size;
     const downvotes = downvoteReaction.users.cache.size;
```

It takes the number of reactions from the first two reactions on the message. Seeing as how the only reactions are thumbs up and thumbs down, it will get the numbers from both of them. From there, you can just compare the two.

Comment: Thanks to the stack overflow member that helped me on the other problem, and as a result found a better strategy for this one.

Comment: There are a few more ways you can do this, but this is the most versatile and easy way I found. Add some more in the comments if you have any!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should beautify your code before you post on stackoverflow, you could have removed the break keyword and just explain it was inside of a switch case

The reason it does not work is because you are checking the `message`'s reaction, and not the embed that you send, so to fix this you need to assign a variable to `message.channel.send(embad)`, but this is a promise so you need to `await` it, which requires an async function

lastly `awaitReactions` and `createReactionCollector` are probably better options,

So here's the new code:

```js
(async () => {
    if (!args[1]) return message.channel.send('You need to specify a person!');
    if (!args[2]) return message.channel.send('Please specify a time for how long the ban council will last.')
    if (!message.guild) return message.channel.send('Banning does not work here');

    var tim = args[2]
    const sweden = message.mentions.member.first()
    const mappo = ['', '']
    message.react('').then(() => message.react(''))

    const embad = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Ban Council')
        .addField('The Convicted:', `${sweden.tag}`)
        .addField('Rules:', 'Vote on whether the convicted is guilty or not with the prompted reactions. The ban will end automatically in 5 seconds.')
    const embedMessage = await message.channel.send(embad);

    setTimeout(function () {
        if (!sweden) return message.reply('You need to mention a person');

        const filter = (reaction) => mappo.includes(reaction.emoji.name);
        embad.awaitReactions(filter, { time: 5000 })
            .then(collection => {
                //not the most optimal way to do it
                const emoji1 = collection.find(e => e.emoji.name === '');
                const emoji2 = collection.find(e => e.emoji.name === '');
                
                //both default to 0
                const upvotes = emoji1 && emoji1.users.size || 0;
                const downvotes = emoji2 && emoji2.users.size || 0;

                if (upvotes > downvotes) {
                    lyft.ban({ reason: 'Majority has exiled you from server. ' })
                        .then(() => message.reply(`The user ${december.tag} was banned as a result of a majority vote.`));
                } else {
                    message.channel.send('The ban was cancelled.');
                }

            })
            .catch(console.error);
    }, tim);
})();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is really helpful. Thanks for explaining all that I did wrong, I've been doing this less than a year, so stuff like this helps tremendously. Sorry I didn't provide cleaner code, and thanks for your help. Hope you have a good day.

Comment: No problem, glad you read it instead of just copying the code, there were a few changes I did that I didn't explain, so just comment if you don't get them, no worries about the clean code part. Lastly I should note SO team is against "thank you" comment, so if you want to show thanks on a correct answer you should accept the post instead.

Comment: Ok, I'm having a problem in which it's saying it cannot read property of 'users' of undefined, not sure how to resolve it. I've been working on it for the past hour, and it's still not working. Hope you can help, if not, I'll keep working on it.

Comment: It's probably because one of the emojis wasn't reacted on, so you will have to check if they exist and then call `.users.size` otherwise default to 0. Edited my post for the difference. Also you shouldn't name them `emoji1` and `emoji2`, I just did it since I can't think of any name currently

Comment: yep! i replaced the area with const upvotes and const upvotes with the code I originally had. Thanks for everything!